# DotNetOpenAuth: Getting the sample OAuth 2.0 AuthorizationServer Working

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am in the process of identifying a framework for building a local OAuth (2.0) Provider with a good client library (there aren’t many), at a glance DotNetOpenAuth seems to be ideal and I got excited and wanted to try out the samples.

I spent few days fiddling with the sample and the source itself still I couldn’t figure out a way to get the OAuth2\AuthorizationServer sample working. Sample works fine for all other external providers. I went through numerous posts to figure out ideal setup, inputs, settings to get pass initial login screen but I had no luck.

Can someone please share the initial steps to be followed to get the OAuth2\AuthorizationServer sample up and running. Including the database setup. I tried stepping through the code but lost it.

Appreciate your time. I am very happy to document the steps if I can understand them clearly. I think the framework is excellent but documentation is lacking. Thanks again!

This is the error I am getting,

**DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements**

I’ve used relying party URI as inputs,
http:// localhost:59722 /
http:// localhost:59722 /SampleWcf2.aspx

And the full stack trace,

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 352
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 354
   at OAuthAuthorizationServer.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in D:\Temp\dotnetopenid\samples\OAuthAuthorizationServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


2012-06-15 16:08:03,490 (GMT+10) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET http://localhost:59722/SampleWcf2.aspx
2012-06-15 16:08:03,498 (GMT+10) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - HTML discovery failed to find any endpoints.
2012-06-15 16:08:03,498 (GMT+10) [16] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Performing discovery on user-supplied identifier: http://localhost:59722/SampleWcf2.aspx
2012-06-15 16:08:03,498 (GMT+10) [16] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Filtering and sorting of endpoints did not affect the list.
2012-06-15 16:08:03,578 (GMT+10) [16] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServer - An unhandled exception occurred in ASP.NET processing: DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 352
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 354
   at OAuthAuthorizationServer.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in D:\Temp\dotnetopenid\samples\OAuthAuthorizationServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 352
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) in d:\Temp\dotnetopenid\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs:line 354
   at OAuthAuthorizationServer.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in D:\Temp\dotnetopenid\samples\OAuthAuthorizationServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing OAuth 2.0 authorization servers with OpenID 2.0 Providers.  They are totally different.  When "logging in" to the authorization server sample, which appears to be the failure point in your original question, you need to enter a valid OpenID.  The URLs you were trying appear to be URLs to the OAuth 2.0 client sample, which isn't an OpenID.

You should log into the authorization server using identifiers like those supplied by the OpenIdProvider sample, or (most easily) just use "yahoo.com" if you have a Yahoo account or "tinyurl.com/googop" to log in using Google.

Comment: Thanks! 

My requirement is to implement a local Authorization Server. I have a API exposes access to secure resources. Client has a trust/credentials to access the API. When users of the Client access the API I want the authorization server to grant access based on previous access grants. 

AuthorizationServer sample seems to be doing this, I managed to get Implicit grants flow working and I need to get the resource owner credentials flow also working.

So I am under the impression that DotNetOpenAuth impalements these constructs, please correct me I am wrong?

Comment: That sounds all good, and yes DotNetOpenAuth supports what you're trying to do.  So just keep in mind when you're logging into the authorization server that you need to provide a valid OpenID (or change the authorization server so that it accepts username+pasword logins to suit you)

Comment: I agree on "lack of documentation" part of this. You created a perfect framework for this but I think many people could not correctly implement this because of missing/lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken (which isn't entirely unlikely) the `AuthorizationServer` sample pretty much acts as a gateway which validates OAuth requests by authorizing the user against an OpenID provider. Instead of putting the relying party's URL in, you might try putting in an OpenID provider URL. (even for testing, you should be fine using any of the [public providers you may have an account with](http://openidexplained.com/get))

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I figured that I have to use the AuthorizationServer base URL (http://localhost:50172/), with that I was able to step further but then it craps out again spitting the same exception.

I was under the impression that DotNetOpenAuth library implements base classes to build a custom OpenID Provider (AuthorizationServer). 
Can someone please conform this? Also has anyone succeeded building one either using DotNetOpenAuth or any other framework?

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Sorry for not replying for so long... I think there's some confusion between the OAuth2 classes and OpenID classes; as far as I know, AuthorizationServer is an OAuth2 authorization server implementation; the OpenID provider class is DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.OpenIdProvider. I had succeeded in building an _OAuth2_ authorization server and client at my previous job. My point in my initial answer was that the sample using AuthorizationServer seems to implement an OAuth2 auth server which just passes authentication through to an OpenID endpoint, which is not provided by the sample.