# use DotNetOpenAuth to connect one site to another both ways

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I want to use DotNetOpenAuth to make a connection from one site that has DotNetOpenAuth to another site that has DotNetOpenAuth so that they can use each other's api.  The goal is to have to make the authorization once then from then on they can do things between each other.  They have to be two different site, both C# castle projects.  To be honest it'll be about 5 of them that will need to talk between each other and use each other's api, so I just want to store the connections once and not worry about them un-connecting.  I have the database set up to store the session and tokens I believe but as it truns out, the docs for DotNetOpenAuth is less then helpful.  *(At the time of writing the [DotNetOpenAuth api doc's](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/master/) site is down)* I'm unclear if this [web.config](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Configuration) set up is all I need to do, which would seem very odd to me, or if there is some example out there that has a more set by step of what I'm asking about.

The question at it's heart is simply, how do you set up one site to authorization another site and store it only once.  The thought is that I have no idea how many of these micro sites there will be in the end, just that they have to make a two way authorized connections and then use each other's api.

All I need is a detailed example of a provider set up for a web app and a client for a web app.  I'm sure they will not be in the same example but I'm having a hard time finding anything that is a clear step by step on either side.  The few convoluted examples have been MVC ones which doesn't help get to the core of it easily.

The end goal is that (Site A) has a connection to (Site B) & (Site C) where (Site C) has a connection to (Site A) & (Site D) meaning that  (Site A),(Site B),(Site C),(Site D) are both a provider and a client and that we'd be storing the tokens normally in a session (from clients point of view) in the database.  It's not needed to have more then the example of how to clearly make a provider and how to make a client as the rest would be apparent on storing.

**UPDATE**
I have been trying to integrate [this example](http://hoonzis.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-dotnetopenauth-to-create-oauth.html), as it's the best one I can find.  The issue is that it's more of a provider as an app verse a site that has the provider in it and the consumer in it.  The issue with the example is that it's not really lining up with the files.  And it breezes over the ideas on key parts.

### visualized concept

[image]

Comment: They can't have a central server, and it's more of (Site A) has a connection to (Site B) & (Site C) where (Site C) has a connection to (Site A) & (Site D) so a SSO I don't think would work here.  Know I have done something sort of like this in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13106146/746758 thou I got beat up for it not being a question.. but it does something like this.  Only diff is that first it's C# client to a php provider, in this case Magento.  But I want to make, as in my example, (Site A) both a provider and a client.  Hope that clears it up, if so I'll update the question.

Comment: Actually your question was clear, I just misread it sorry (but at 4 in the morning kind of hard lol). Yep SSO has nothing to do with what you want, I'll delete my comment since it's irrelevant.

Comment: You don't mention *users* at all in your question. So if it's just a matter of 5 web sites all calling each other programmatically, why not use HTTPS and a shared secret (HTTP Basic authorization perhaps) and be done with it? Using OAuth would be inappropriate.

Comment: @AndrewArnott thank you for piping in.. Yes you 100% I did skip the user part just because I figured that would muddy the water, but they would be in the mix after

Comment: after... what? If these 5 web sites all totally trust each other (they're all in-house, so to speak), then a shared secret across them all still makes sense. OAuth is useful when web sites that don't share a two-way trust already want to access resources that belong to 3rd parties (users).

Comment: @AndrewArnott I have added a visual to hopefully clear up what I need to do.  The after was in reference to that once I have the site to site, the since I'll be using much of the same methods treating sites and devices summarily, I would just add them after I get the sites connected and talking. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: What are you using for Authenticating the users?

Comment: nothing yet, the goal is to let them authenticate thru the same setup.  In other words, when a site authenticates to another site, it's just the same as a user authenticating to a site.  This is the basically same thing as that php project example I put up in the linked question.

Comment: It's not though is it.  Authentication and Authorisation are two very different things.  Once you have authenticated a user (FormsAuth with a local SQLdb, OpenID) on the server side you'll then using OAuth to access another sites resources.

Comment: I get that, everything needs to be in one.  I'm tring to reproduce what is done in the php app Magento, here.  It lets you set up roles, and authorize tokens.  The only difference is that I will be making a site act as a user.  So there are two side to this, one, do all the server side stuff, regardless of terms here, a user needs to use oAuth to access the api.  The server is standalone.  once this is done then it's just fake being a user.  All this is why I was asking about a clear step by step.  pulling threads out has be fruitless on such a complicated process.

Comment: @AndrewArnott and Jammer what is the thought here, should I be what, making AuthorisationServer implementations with in the site's bases? keeping track of the consumers in the DB and then make a consumer controller in the site base and store the session for the sites?  or.. I want to form a simple plan lol..

Comment: Based on this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11141364/746758 I don't want to make an AuthorisationServer as that requires an OpenID provider.  So I need to do what I thought the first time right? Make a provider and a consumer?

Comment: Authorization Servers do not require OpenID Providers. Just because a sample happens to combine both shouldn't be understood as that the combination is necessary. You can authenticate users any way you want on an authorization server.

Comment: ok, I'll look down that path, it was not crystal and I guess it just is a little bounce around and you'll stump on the right path for me atm with this topic.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @AndrewArnott so which two (I'm assuming two) in the samples should I be looking at to get the setup I'm seeking?  OAuthAuthorizationServer or the OAuth2ProtectedWebApi .. OAuthClient or OAuthConsumer .. or is it a combo of them all or am I even looking to the right ones?  as much help to get the right path here would be super in assisting in production the solution to the project.

Comment: You're doing something unique here, so no sample or pair will be exactly right. I suggest you study all the ones you mentioned to learn how DNOA works so you can create your own unique solution.

Comment: @AndrewArnott I don't mean to sound argumentative to the author, but, other then I push two processes together (site authorizing a access to an api, & an app that uses the api), how is this unique?  In the end I really just want to know what should be followed to produce the needed parts.  If your saying I need to join the samples OAuthAuthorizationServer & the OAuth2ProtectedWebApi to do the authorization of a api to a user/app/what have you, I'll work that out.  It's just not as straight forward to someone not in the know trying to get there, to pick out what samples to base off of is all.

Comment: The uniqueness is that you're not just pushing two together. You're pushing five. And maybe "unique" is too strong a word. The point is that anything beyond the boilerplate common scenarios of just creating one end (either client or server), or creating one of each, anything else requires custom authoring, custom threat models, etc. And how to create such a custom, application-specific thing isn't just a Q&A level answer. It involves designing the whole solution, which is more consultation level. Or study the samples and docs and create it yourself.

Comment: @AndrewArnott So, as I'm trying to follow examples out there, and I split the tasks up in two side, server & client.  I was following the http://hoonzis.blogspot.com example I listed in the question.  It seemed like one thing to grant access to an api.  Is it not an ok thing to follow given that for the first task is "Granting access" to an api?  Once I have that first task down then I'll roll the second task of a client authenticating to use an api.  I've been bouncing around a lot and I'm just trying to come to the line of attack to run down is all.  Thanks for coming back to guide.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this as a [base for your AuthorisationServer](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/samples/OAuthAuthorizationServer/Code/OAuth2AuthorizationServer.cs) implementation and share the library across all the API solutions.

The centralised solution you mention could be a good plan depending on how you want to structure the overall architecture of the various API implementations.  Really difficult to suggest anything on that front as it really depends on how you want it to all hang together.

If you went with the centralised approach you would have to give each API a key and a secret and create an entry in an ClientAuthorisation table in the database for each API.  My Authorisation table looks like this at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApiClientAuthorizations](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ApiClientId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UserProfileId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Scope] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Expires] [datetime] NULL,
```

The key field in here is the Scope which defines the level of access any client has.  As far as I know you would only need to implement a provider if you actually wanted to start letting other systems make use of your implementation to secure their own services using your system as their identity store which I really don't think you need to do in order to satisfy your requirements for this.

I found getting the a lot of samples to actually work was very time consuming but the code in the samples really is very good and worth studying closely to get a better feel for what is actually going on under the hood.

Comment: so you said you have one working?  care to share a striped down working version? I'm not quite fallowing that sample so maybe seeing it done two ways it'll click.

Comment: To be honest my implementation really doesn't stray very far from the class I linked to in the DNOA samples.  OAuth is a complex topic that you really do need to study, if not for your own peace of mind but out of responsibility to your end users as well.  Have a look through the OAuth 2 spec? It's worth looking at that in conjunction with the samples from Andrew as it will answer some questions about why things are done the way they are.  You can find the [RFC Here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Comment: yeah I read thru that rfc a while back and even thru the oauth site it's self too.  Just a muddy water something when getting in the usage of the libs.  The magento project boned me up on the php side, I just needed to reproduce it on this side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to be a provider to implement this.  I'd make a generic implementation of an authorisation server and manually set up authorisations within the database for each site you wish to communicate with on each server.

Use SSL certs for encryption and you should be good to go with OAuth2.0 tokens being sent around for authorising the API calls.

Comment: That sounds a lot like ppetrov's suggestion of a central server for the sites to authenticate against.  This not able to be nor what is wanted.  If your not making the same suggestion, please provide an example as it's not so much theories I'm after but how tos.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are a lot of examples that come with DNOA itself, I based my implementation of the Authorisation Server on some of the example code I found and altered it to fit my needs (not a lot of changes to be honest) The centralised server sounds like it could work but I guess it depends how much similarity there is between the different APIs you are building.  It might be more flexible to create a library with your code in referenced by each API and a standardised database schema so each API has it's own database?

Comment: It's not about if there is a standardized DB schema here, as yes there mostly is, but it's about control & resources. The deployment is by many different parties, & there is not resource to centralize. That is why its a must that the goal is that (Site A) has a connection to (Site B) & (Site C) where (Site C) has a connection to (Site A) & (Site D). I have looked thru the DNOA examples & github, but to me it's not crystal clear.  That is why I was looking for step by step & simplified clear, this is a provider minimal set up, and this is a minimal consumer setup, plus most examples were OpenID

Comment: OpenID is for authentication, what you're looking for is Authorisation - OAuth2.0 is pretty much a server side mechanism for allowing services access to the resources.  Also there are no "connections" as such just the exchange of bearer tokens which grant clients access to resources.  I struggled with this at the start and am still in the process of completing my own implementation.  What you describe doesn't require a provider at all, just an authorisation server to grant the access.

Comment: That is what I'm saying thou, there can't be a authorization server.  Each site must act as it's own.  As I pointed out to ppetrov's http://stackoverflow.com/q/13106146/746758 is a good example of what needs to be done.  Thou it's php, Magento lets others authorize for access, but there is no central.  I could hook one site to another if I wished, set the authorization and store the tokens long term and let them talk back and forth between each other.  This is the same effect I need to do in C# that was done in PHP

Comment: I think you have the terminology mixed up.  You simply cannot achieve what you want without an authorisation server in there somewhere authorising the calls between APIs.  You want to use OAuth not OpenID ... a provider is OpenID that PROVIDES identity (authentication) services to a relying party.  What you want to do (as far as I can tell) is authorisation, not authentication.

Comment: Yes said that the ex:'s in DNOA were OpenID heavy & needed to find examples of OAuth set ups. "Provider" came from the hoonzis.blogspot.com above site.  Really it's just that I need the sites to do what the Magento app is. I need to store & authorize it's consumers. I need to also need to let the site be a consumer as well where it's tokens are stored in the DB not sessions as demonstrated in that other question. I know it's a little muddy but that is why I simple need an example for the goal of (SiteA) has a connection to (SiteB) & (SiteC) where (SiteC) has a connection to (SiteA) & (SiteD)

Comment: To be honest I'm confused about what you want now as well.  I think you need to start implementing what you need and start new questions when you have a specific problem.  Good luck.